# Android - alert expand

Tags: android, alert

In my Alert in Adroid, I would be able to have a checkbox, which will expand after tick the same alert and new objects (buttons) will appear. I haven't found anything yet, if it is possible or not. Is there anyone who tried it already?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of expanding the same alert, create a new one. The rest of your question is simple UI interaction and need to be much more detailed if you have a problem with that.